# Swipe to swap two containers in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have two containers horizontally positioned.

How to use `GestureDetector`, to detect swipe (from top to bottom or from bottom to top) and swipe these containers with some animation?

I attach a picture:
[image]

If you swipe from C2 to C1 (or C1 to C2) these containers will swap.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are lots of better solution but you can look at this for a temporary workaround:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TestPage());
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  double address1Top = 20;
  double address2Top = 110;
  bool isFirstUp = true;
  bool isSecondUp = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 150,
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
     
          Positioned(
            top: isFirstUp ? address1Top : address2Top,
            left: 20,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
                if (details.delta.dy > 1 && isFirstUp) {
                  setState(() {
                    isFirstUp = false;
                    isSecondUp = true;
                  });
                }

                if (details.delta.dy < -1 && isSecondUp) {
                  setState(() {
                    isFirstUp = true;
                    isSecondUp = false;
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 140,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("A"),
                ),
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // Bottom address
          Positioned(
            top: isSecondUp ? address1Top : address2Top,
            left: 20,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
               if (details.delta.dy < -1 && isFirstUp) {
                  setState(() {
                    isFirstUp = false;
                    isSecondUp = true;
                  });
                }

                if (details.delta.dy > 1 && isSecondUp) {
                  setState(() {
                    isFirstUp = true;
                    isSecondUp = false;
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 140,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text("B"),
                ),
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can set smaller than `-1` and bigger than `1` for more sensitive.

Comment: It is possible to implement swapping animation here? (for instance like swapping items on listview)

Comment: Of course. You can look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59871812/10659482