# How to Swap two row in column flutte?

Tags: flutter, dart

in flutter app I have two rows in one column
And I want to perform the swap operation on these two lines,

I tried the following link, but it didn't work:

### https://alex.domenici.net/archive/swapping-two-widgets-in-flutter-inverting-their-positions-with-or-without-animation

[How to animate the swap of 2 items in a Row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65175065/how-to-animate-the-swap-of-2-items-in-a-row)

[image]

and in this code:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: _buildAppBar(),
  body: Padding(
    padding: AppPadding.paddingContentPages,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 32),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                _buildTop(),
                _margin(),
                _buildRowLocationMap(),]
```

```
Widget _buildTop() {
 

  return Row(
    children: [
      _buildListSide(),
      const SizedBox(width: 8),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [

               Row(
                children: [
                 Expanded(child: _buildOrigin()),
                ],),

            _margin(),
          Row(children: [
              Expanded(child: _buildDestination()),
              ]),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(width: 8),
      _buildArrowSwap(),
    ],
  );
}
```

I hope you will answer me

Answer (score 0):

you can simply implement this

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
  List<Widget> items=[
    Row(
              children:[Text("Row 1")]
            ),
    
              Row(
              children:[Text("Row 2")]
            ),
    
          ];
  
  void _change() {
     items.swap(0,1);
    setState(()=>{});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: items
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _change,
        tooltip: 'Change',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> list extension

```
extension SwappableList<E> on List<E> {
  void swap(int first, int second) {
    final temp = this[first];
    this[first] = this[second];
    this[second] = temp;
  }
}
```

or

[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871239/how-to-animate-interchanging-widgets-in-flutter)